# How to call two returned local variables from a function to verify as a condition in another function in python?

Tags: python, function

The question is this :

Write a Python function to find all the Strong numbers in a given list of numbers.
Write another function to find and return the factorial of a number. Use it to solve the problem.
Note: 0!=1

The code I tried so far :

```
def factorial(number):
    sum1=0
    temp=number
    while(number):
        i=1
        f=1
        r=number%10
        while(i<=r):
            f=f*i
            i=i+1
            sum1=sum1+f
            number=number//10
    return sum1
    return temp

def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
     for item in num_list:
         for number in range(1,item+1):
            if(sum1==temp):
                print(number)

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10]
strong_num_list=find_strong_numbers(num_list)
print(strong_num_list)
```

Expected output : [145, 2]

I am facing error which is :

NameError: name 'sum1' is not defined

Comment: What is a "strong" number?  It sounds like you're looking for something more like `[factorial(num) for num in num_list if is_strong_num(num)]`

Comment: A number is considered to be a Strong number if sum of the factorial of its digits is equal to the number itself. 
145 is a Strong number as 1! + 4! + 5! = 145.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

def factorial(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)

def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
     strongNumbersList = []
     for item in num_list:
         currentNumber = item
         digits = []
         while currentNumber > 0:
            digits.insert(0, currentNumber % 10)
            currentNumber = currentNumber // 10
         if sum(map(factorial, digits)) == item:
             strongNumbersList.append(item)
     return strongNumbersList

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10]

strong_num_list=find_strong_numbers(num_list)

print(strong_num_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

import math

def factorial(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)

def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
     strongNumbersList = []
     for item in num_list:
         currentNumber = item
         digits = []
         while currentNumber > 0:
            digits.insert(0, currentNumber % 10)
            currentNumber = currentNumber // 10
         if sum(map(factorial, digits)) == item:
            if item==0:
                 break
            strongNumbersList.append(item)
     return strongNumbersList

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10,40585,0]

strong_num_list=find_strong_numbers(num_list)

print(strong_num_list)

1. **List item**

Comment: actually there was one problem every time zero also includes so if we are cheching   num_list=[145,375,100,0,10]  for result that time zero also included so its worng ……….my solution is correct in every condition